# PerformanceProgressBar in Standard WPF

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I was looking for a busy indicator to use in my wpf application.  After looking around for some time and finding a few good examples I thought why don't i use the busy indicator that my window phone 7 uses.

So i found PerformanceProgressBar at http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/performanceprogressbar/.  This is included in silverlight toolkit now.

It converts straight over to my wpf app but the performance is horrible.  The boxes move across the screen as they should but the movement is choppy.  It has a size issue but that's a different topic.

Running the exact same code on on my phone gives a very smooth animation and the emulator.  Any ideas why?  Also tried it in a simple silverlight web app and it's smooth as could be.

The code creates 5 rectangles then moves them across the screen using a storyboard updating the x value of a TranslateTransform.  They are defining CacheMode="BitmapCache" on each rectangle.

I have a good developer machine (quad core, 8 gig ram) with an ok video card (NVidia GeForce 9300 GE)

thanks for any feedback.
scott

Answer (score 3):

You can find the BusyIndicator in the WPFExtendedToolKit as well..
http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Extended%20WPF%20Toolkit%20Controls

try out using this one ...